# How to turn Python code into C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.2

How should I write a code which does the same in  C++? I'm finding it quite difficult..

```
### X,Y and Z will all be integers (numbers). The user will input a number 3 three times   thus determining the type of triangle###

x = int(input("Input your first length:  "))
y = int(input("Input your second length: "))
z = int(input("Input your third length: "))

### "=" is an equality operater. If the side of x, y and x are all equal the triangle will be equilateral.###

if  (x == y == z):
    print ("The program recognises this as an Equilateral triangle.")
```

Comment: Don't "convert" but "write" some new code in C++ ... Of course you need to read a good C++ programming book.

Comment: The Python code is hardly an algorithm; you take 3 integers from the user and test if they are all equal. You could have described that in one sentence.

Comment: Create a python parser in haskell which would generate some C++ code. (jk)

Answer (score 2):

I won't write the code for you, but I will give you some guidance:

1. Do a "Hello World" tutorial in C++
2. Use std::cin to read in each length (see the header [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/))
3. Look up the equivalent operators (i.e. equality and logical AND) and conditional statement

That's the most help you'll get, short of writing the code for you (which is not helpful for your learning).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x, y, z;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cin >> z;

    if (x == y && x == z)
        std::cout << "equilateral" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that there is no `==` operator with three operands in C++. `(x == y) == z` would compare x to y and return true or false. Then it would compare true/false to z which is not what you want.